# Google places pagination ios

Tags: ios, pagination, google-places-api

Hi i am using google api to list shoppping mall near by my location.While calling it list many shopping mall, is there a way to do pagination in google places.I want to list only first ten items first.Also i want to know, in the above api i have given my location as kochi, is it possible to give our latitude longitude as location to retreive data.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=SHOPPINGMALL+in+kochi&key=Key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Place API now supports pagination of up to 60 results.

The Places API will return up to 20 establishments per query; however, each search can return as many as 60 results, split across three pages. If your search will return more than 20, then the search response will include an additional parameter — next_page_token. Pass the value of next_page_token to the page_token parameter of a new place search to see the next set of 20 results.

2.it is possible to give our latitude longitude as location to retrieve data, check the below request
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

Comment: If it is enough for ur question, please do the tickmark

Comment: I need to list nearby shopping mall,hotels,offices etc based on lat, lon.Is it possible?

Comment: you can specify ,types — Restricts the results to places matching at least one of the specified types. Types should be separated with a pipe symbol (type1|type2|etc). See the list of supported types(https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types).